# What is a "psychological evaluation" for kids?

Tags: test, depression

What does a psychological evaluation consist of for pre-teens and adolescents?

I work with a child who has been abused (physically and emotionally) who is having suicidal ideations with one parent, but is also having problems with the "good" parent who is also supposedly making them feel like they don't like the other parent (which I don't think is actually true). The authorities have come in and determined that the child needs a "psychological evaluation" and I'm trying to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

First, they must assess whether intervention is necessary in a episode of acute crisis.

http://psychiatryonline.org/pb/assets/raw/sitewide/practice_guidelines/guidelines/suicide.pdf

Subsequently, the evaluation that must be carried out by an expert aims to determine the psychological impact in the present, if it is advisable to follow up and that possible implications would take place in the future.

http://www.apa.org/helpcenter/assessment.aspx